# Update Pickup location in google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to show the current position based on user lat & long:
Drop off location always stay static but pick up location (icon) need to move as per lat long, but i am not find the correct way my code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var map;

function initialize() {

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        suppressMarkers: true
    });

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    calcRoute();
}

function calcRoute(pickUpLat,pickUplon,droplat,droplon) {
    var pickUpLat   = "<?= $pickUpLat ?>";
    var pickUplon   = "<?= $pickUplon ?>";
    var droplat     = "<?= $model->drop_off_latitude ?>";
    var droplon     = "<?= $model->drop_off_longitude ?>";
    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(pickUpLat,pickUplon);
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(droplat,droplon);

    createMarker(start,"<?= $model->item_delivery_title; ?>","<?= Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontEnd->createAbsoluteUrl('/images/track_route.png')?>");
    createMarker(end,"<?= $model->drop_off_address; ?>",'');

    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            var route = response.routes[0];
        }
    });
}

function createMarker(latlng,title,icon) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: title,
        icon: icon,
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.setContent(title);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}

initialize();

function makeRequest(){
        $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo Url::base(true).'/delivery/map-data'; ?>",
        type:"POST",
        data:{"delivery_id":<?= $model->id ?>}

        })
        .done(function(result){
            var respon=JSON.parse(result);
            if(respon.status==200){
                // want to cupdate the pickup location here
            }


        });

    } 
    setInterval(makeRequest, (3000));

});
```

Make request function always update the pick up lat and long:
But I am not found any way to move the pick up icon (the van) see image :
[image]

The red marker is drop off address and the van is pickup address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create two variables for pick up and drop off marker. Also your createMarker function should return marker instance. After you receive request from server update pickUpMarker position.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var map;
var pickUpMarker, dropToMarker; // add marker variables


function initialize() {

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        suppressMarkers: true
    });

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    calcRoute();
}

function calcRoute(pickUpLat,pickUplon,droplat,droplon) {
    var pickUpLat   = "<?= $pickUpLat ?>";
    var pickUplon   = "<?= $pickUplon ?>";
    var droplat     = "<?= $model->drop_off_latitude ?>";
    var droplon     = "<?= $model->drop_off_longitude ?>";
    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(pickUpLat,pickUplon);
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(droplat,droplon);

    if(!pickUpMarker) {
        pickUpMarker = createMarker(start,"<?= $model->item_delivery_title; ?>","<?= Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontEnd->createAbsoluteUrl('/images/track_route.png')?>");
    } else {
        pickUpMarker.setPosition(start)
    }

    if(!dropToMarker) {
        dropToMarker = createMarker(end,"<?= $model->drop_off_address; ?>",'');
    } else {
        dropToMarker.setPosition(start)
    }

    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            var route = response.routes[0];
        }
    });
}

function createMarker(latlng,title,icon) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: title,
        icon: icon,
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.setContent(title);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    return marker;
}

initialize();
function makeRequest(){
    $.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo Url::base(true).'/delivery/map-data'; ?>",
    type:"POST",
    data:{"delivery_id":<?= $model->id ?>}

    })
    .done(function(result){
        var respon=JSON.parse(result);
        if(respon.status==200){
            // want to cupdate the pickup location here
            pickUpMarker.setPosition(result.position)
        }


    });

} 
setInterval(makeRequest, (3000));

});
```

Comment: let me know if it helps :)

Comment: Could you please help me to pass data in  pickUpMarker.setPosition(result.position), I assume it should be as pickUpMarker.setPosition({lat:30.45,lon:70.36}) ? but not working

Comment: latlng object consist of lat and lng not lat and lon {lat: 30.45, lng: 70.36}
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/coordinates#LatLng

Comment: Hi Šarūnas Guobis is it  possible to update the path ? the marker is being update but path is not updating

Comment: Yes you can. You need request directionsService to get routes for new starting and ending points positions. In your  makeRequest method, then you getting response calculate route and change markers positions.

Comment: Could you please guide me how to do that ?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/leyagijiji/edit?js,output created jsbin for you. It can require some modification, but it should work.

Comment: Yes, its works i did some modification. You're a lifesaver, Thanks

Comment: Glad it helped :)